# Global Variable in Userform

Tags: vba, global-variables, userform

I search about this in the forum and found some answers but did not work for me.

I have two UserForms.

In the first one, I give a value to a variable called Word.

In the second one, I have a Label that I need the caption to become the variable Word.

Example:

```
Public Word as String

Private Sub Userform1_Activate
   Word = "Today Is Saturday"
End Sub

Private Sub Userform2_Activate
   Label1.Caption = Word
End Sub
```

But this does not work. The Label caption gets Zero for value. 
Could anybody help me on this?

Thanks.

```
First Form

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Db = "C:\Users\Desktop\db.txt"

Set File1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File2 = File1.OpenTextFile(Db, 1)

Do Until File2.AtEndOfStream

If (File2.Readline = TextBox1) Then Exit Do
If File2.AtEndOfStream Then WordNotFound.Show
If File2.AtEndOfStream Then TextBox1.Value = ""
If File2.AtEndOfStream Then Exit Sub

Loop

Word = File2.Readline

MsgBox Word

TextBox1.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Second Form

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

Label1.Caption = Word

End Sub
```

Comment: This should work. Can you show the sequence of showing the user forms?

Comment: I have added them to my first post, take a look.

Comment: See my sample code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in my comment, that your method should work. Here is the test code that I tried

1- In `Module1`

```
Public Word As String
```

2- Create 2 user forms - `UserForm1` and `UserForm2`

2a- In UserForm1

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Word = "This is Saturday"
End Sub
```

2b- In UserForm2

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Label1.Caption = Word
End Sub
```

3- Then in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

So when you close UserForm1, the UserForm2 would be displayed as below

[image]

Comment: Pankaj Jaju, your code works well.
But I intend to use only Useforms. Cant I do it just by using the two useforms?

Because I'd like to create a exe file later. And if it's using "ThiwWorkbook" and a Module, I am not sure it will be possible

Comment: I only showed you my test code. You can implement the `.Show` anywhere you want. For e.g, you can use `UserForm2.Show` in the end of `UserForm1` code. Just ensure that the `Word` is set before you call `UserForm2`

Comment: Oh, thanks, I get it!
But what about the Public Word as String statement ? Does it need to go in a separated module?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have it at the beginning of UserForm code.

Comment: Hi, two user forms are two different objects. The variable `Word` must be defined as Public and assume it is defined in `Userform1`. Everywhere else this variable is accessible with "dot notation" as `Userfrom1.Word`.